Possible degrees of this finite morphism to $\mathbb{P}^3$
The context of this question is the same as another one I previously asked on this site but I'm going to write it down again.
Let $X$ be a K3 surface, whose Picard group is generated by a line bundle $L$ with self-intersection $(L)^2=4$. In particular, since $(L)^2>0$, $X$ is projective and we can suppose $L$ is ample (up to considering its dual). Riemann-Roch and Kodaira vanishing theorem allow us to calculate the dimension of the global sections of $L$
$$h^0(X,L)=4.$$
Then, the fact that $L$ generates $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ implies that all the curves in the linear system $|L| are irreducible and we can apply Lemma 2.3 from Huybrechts' Lectures on K3 surfaces stating that

$L$ is base point free and the induced morphism $$\varphi_L: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$$
restricts to the canonical map on a generic smooth irreducible curve $C \in |L|$
$$\varphi_{\omega_C}: C \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2.$$

I want to study the different possible degrees of $\varphi_L$. In Huybrechts' book, just two cases are distinguished: the generic member of $|L|$ is hyperelliptic (then $\varphi_L$ has degree two) or the generic member of $|L|$ is not hyperelliptic (then $\varphi_L$ is birational).
I know that the degree of the morphism multiplied by the degree of the image of $X$ is equal to $4=(L)^2$, but I don't get why we exclude the case $\operatorname{deg}(\varphi_L)=4$. In this case we would have $\varphi_L(X)$ has degree 1 in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and maybe this contradicts the fact that the map restricts to the canonical morphism on $C$ but I'm not sure. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

If the degree of the image is 1, the image is a plane, and the pullback of the equation of this plane to $X$ vanishes. But by definition of a morphism given by $L$, the pullback of the map
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}(1)) \otimes \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(1)
$$
is the map
$$
H^0(X,L) \otimes \mathcal{O} \to L,
$$
hence the pullback of any global section of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is a non-trivial global section of $L$.
